# Spring Cloud Load Balancer - Is there a way to see which instance is choosen?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

We're switching from Ribbon to Spring Cloud Load Balancer, and thus far things seem to work.  However I want to be able to see which instance is chosen on each request to verify the behavior.

Is there a debug flag or some other way to see which instance SCLB is choosing on each request?

Answer (score 0):

The selected service instances are logged for debug in various places on the client side, for example in [`ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/a1f408c8e17ee60d1402323479032e2e181902a0/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/reactive/ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction.java#L127-L130), in [`RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/a1f408c8e17ee60d1402323479032e2e181902a0/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java#L96-L99), in [`RetryableLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/a1f408c8e17ee60d1402323479032e2e181902a0/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/reactive/RetryableLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction.java#L154-L157), etc. Also,for `WebClient`-backed load-balancing [you can enable setting instance Id as a cookie](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#request-based-sticky-session-for-loadbalancer). You can also [enable Micrometer support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#loadbalancer-micrometer-stats-lifecycle), which will register various useful metrics, including instance ids. Additionally, you can implement your own logging mechanism using the [`LoadBalancerLifecycle` callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#loadbalancer-lifecycle).